# MYSQL Find (and Delete) Word Prefixes and Suffixes

Tags: mysql

Let's say I have a MYSQL table with the following data in one column:

```
marine
submarine
way
subway
subjugate
submission
mission
```

I want to find (and delete) rows that have "sub" as the prefix IF AND ONLY IF another row exists with the root word. So in this example I want to delete "submarine", "subway", and "submission" but NOT "subjugate" (since "jugate" doesn't exist).

How can I do this?

UPDATE: Okay, thank you @Akina. I am getting a:

```
#1054 - Unknown column 't1.word' in 'where clause'
```

when I try. This is my version:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM `en` AS t1, `en` AS t2 
WHERE LEFT(t1.word, 3) = 'sub'
AND t1.word = CONCAT('sub', t2.word)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hmmm... interesting philosophical debates possible here. The words `mission` and `submission` have different meanings - to submit to someone else might mean (or not) subverting one's own mission? Seagulls are marine creatures but are not submarine. Have you looked at any of the academic work in this area regarding [NLP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_processing) and [stemming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stemming)/[derivation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morphological_derivation)? Also, your SQL version could be very important. p.s. welcome to the forum! :-)

Comment: Again ... you should know how the column containing those words is named ... my crystal bowl doesn't light up nor shows what you see ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DELETE t1.*
FROM table t1, table t2
WHERE LEFT(t1.word, 3) = 'sub'
  AND t1.word = CONCAT('sub', t2.word)
```

Comment: See my comment - I think that the OP is looking for a (much) more general solution?

Comment: @Vérace I have seen... and I think that the values are synthetic.

Comment: @Akina This is probably a dumb question, but I tried that and am getting:
#1054 - Unknown column 't1.word' in 'where clause'

Comment: you need to enclose reserved words in backticks in mysql-server .. so table - or replace it with the actual name of the table that you want to deal with

Comment: better edit your original post with that .. as comments are limited ^^

Comment: To be faster, change `LEFT(t1.word, 3) = "sub"` to `t1.word LIKE "sub%'" _and_ have `INDEX(word)`.  (cf "sargeable" and "range")

Comment: @RickJames *To be faster ...* and convert 2nd expression to `some_fn(t1.word) = t2.word`  - it allows to use index by 2nd copy instead of scan by both.